# org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabase:conf/tomcat-users.xml] could not be found(java.io.IOException: Too many open files)

Tags: java, tomcat9

> Server exception
> 10-Aug-2022 10:59:30.517 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabase.backgroundProcess Reloading memory user database [UserDatabase] from updated source [file:/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml]
> 10-Aug-2022 10:59:30.517 SEVERE [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabase.open The specified user database [conf/tomcat-users.xml] could not be found
> 10-Aug-2022 10:59:30.696 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-8443-Acceptor] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Acceptor.run Socket accept failed
> java.io.IOException: Too many open files
> at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
> at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:421)
> at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:249)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.serverSocketAccept(NioEndpoint.java:546)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.serverSocketAccept(NioEndpoint.java:79)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Acceptor.run(Acceptor.java:129)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

```
    Server version: Apache Tomcat/9.0.63
    Server built:   May 11 2022 07:52:11 UTC
    Server number:  9.0.63.0
    OS Name:        Linux
    OS Version:     3.10.0-1160.71.1.el7.x86_64
    Architecture:   amd64
    JVM Version:    1.8.0_332-b09
    JVM Vendor:     Red Hat, Inc.
```

After migration from tomcat 7 to tomcat 9. then randomly seen this exception.

Analysis

1. It is same webapp code from tomcat 7 to tomcat 9 so resource are closed properly with try and finally block as we have not seen the exception in tomcat 7.
2. Some places it is mentioned as increase in ulimit but not sure what is cause for this.

Comment: any suggestions would be grt help